# (Typescript) Enforce types between functions in an array

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm new to Typescript and I'm trying to write definition files for some functions of mine, to practice with the type system.

I would like to write the definition of a function similar to `createSelector` of `redux-js/reselect`.
The function will be called like this:

```
const sel = buildSelector([
   state => state.pages,
   state => state.n,
   (pages, n) => pages[n]
]);
```

The first N-1 functions are simple pre-selectors that take a slice of the state,
the last function is a combiner that will receive all the slices and do the calculations.

So I want something that will enforce the types T0, T1,... Tn for:

```
[
   State => T0,
   State => T1,
   ...
   State => Tn,
   (T0, T1,...,Tn) => any
]
```

I'm using an array because in the next step I would like to pass to the function an object filled with multiple arrays like this to build multiple selectors.

I would like to have the types of all arguments in the combiner function inferred by TS using the return types of pre-selectors. The type of state is fixed (just for this example).

I don't even know if it's possibile to write a correct type for a function like this, anyway this is what I've tried:

```
type State = {pages: string[], n :number};

type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

type ReturnTypes<U extends AnyFunction[]> = {
    [K in keyof U]: U[K] extends AnyFunction ? ReturnType<U[K]> : never;
}

type FnWithArgs<L extends any[]> = (...args:L) => any;

type PreSelector = (state:State) => any;

function buildSelector<
    K extends PreSelector[], 
    F = FnWithArgs<ReturnTypes<K>>,
> 
    (selcfg: [...K, F]) {
    //...code...
}
```

The type of pre-selectors looks good, but the combiner function is `(any, any)=>any`.
My idea was to extract the return type from pre-selectors and build the combiner function with them as arguments... but obviously it doesn't work :)
Any suggestion? Thanks

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8pngcwgLigGdgAnASwDtsAaTHCQg48qgbQF1aKo8KBXALYAjCCQC+AbgCwAKFmhIUAIIUQAMT4UAxsDIB7bqgAUAOjPwS2RlHiqOASijIAfDdXS5MhdABKEYHwkFAAq4AwAPACqUBAAHkgUACaEyqoa2roGHK6oaLJQBVCsANJQlFAA1hAgegBmUJHsBJEl7DHxEEkpKuqaOvrcAPxQfgFBoZBRra4EFBAAbqIeYrLyYVBqFADqZMAAFkqWhOEAMu0JyW4g2U5QpuZHeCeOLlcea4oACiQQMBAANhAdHoSLcjMREPg4JCXq5bCB3jJan1MtwhHwyP9En9AcCSOF8oVSnELilvr8AUDgCCOLRCQU1LdNjt9ocrOFRoEQmFjsVnM5qPSoMEmdtdgcjhz-FyJhE+a4APQKqB8QgQRJQalQH5jbj7aDeKC1EGahi6KiyVxC8EArS1bAEVhmEzFWhqdiOAgYWp4NS0YB4EVidBCpVkARgQECToIVFQCh6YBlCMghAUJOhhUAAWAhAAtGRsAmflAhTqufG+P9-hJSzIVp5ZFoDMQiADbujMdjKXijKxrYRYUQTFhcIRaIVJ1OlVBmyQfjpNeBKNg7tCkPYXMwVxwB0PCCYKBOpyfJzO5z900uwCu17GIJvnPxhKJraOGFwh+-CKwKJxp8qACSUAAO56FWGr-GQVR3NubD-s+IgkPYsgeoishKuWQTXtAZApPAiSJOqmp6KarZ7KI+CrDIar-CYwB9gARPAjH-gArPYtaFDOIp7PAKQXlS163uCpA7pwiGiChNEAvRRgACy0BxXEnjOACi84mhRPy0Ngeh6IkACE1G0SYtQKdQymngUSr-PpFQpFBMGMnxjl6K23gpEY8K0PC0nUUAA)

Comment: This is a tough one! I am able to make [some improvement](https://tsplay.dev/gWoojW) so that `pages` and `n` both get types `string[] | number`, but I can't get those types separated and applied to the right individual variables.

Comment: Yea, inferring tuples from arrays is another hard thing... Anyway I just discovered that adding the explicit type to the preselectors (`(s:State)=>s.pages`) is enough to infer the right parameters on combiner! I'm reading more and more stuff here on SO, and maybe it has something to do with a TS unsupported feature (existential types)...  still investigating...